# Store data for session with an expiration date

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, session-storage

I am building a mobile application in Angular (Ionic 5 to be precise) and I need a way to keep session data during my users workflow.

I considered using the sessionStorage for that, but one important thing is that my user session should expire automatically after 5 minutes. So I would like to store data and reset those data if the user finish the workflow or reset them if the user didn't finished the workflow within 5 minutes.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the expiry time along with the data in `sessionStorage` and when reading the key, check the time to make sure it is still valid for usage.

See [this article](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript-localstorage-with-ttl-expiry/) for reference.

I can't include a Stack Snippet here because it fails on security privileges (editing the localStorage etc.), so here's the link to try this [on GitHub](https://lraj22.github.io/overflow-code/expireStorage/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the user reaction events(click, keypress, ...etc) to refresh your session and made any control you want ! something like `(click)="refreshSession()"`. All your controls will be made inside the `refreshSession()`